# Swap 1.2MB Floppy Drive with 360KB Drive in Older PC

Tags: floppy

I have an old PC with a 5.25 1.2MB floppy drive that is running DOS/Win98. I also have some 360KB floppy drives pulled from an old Kaypro 1 that I would like to put into this machine, but I'm not sure what additional hardware/software is required to support this, if it's even possible.

If the motherboard already supports a 1.2MB floppy drive, is it safe to assume I can just swap this out for an older 360KB drive? Does this depend on the motherboard (the embedded floppy drive controller)? Are the connections the same on both a 1.2MB drive and a 360KB drive? Thanks in advance for your help, below are the specs of this machine if that helps:

```
Athlon 1.5GHz
512MB DDR RAM
80GB IDE Hard Drive
3.5" Floppy
5.25" Floppy 1.2MB
PCI Wireless card that’s compatible with Windows 98SE
```

Comment: It seems like this question could be easily answered if you just pop the case open and look at the connectors.

Comment: I think 1.2 MB drives can also read and write 360 kB floppies. Why swap the drives?

Comment: @MSalters, because a 3.5" floppy doesn't fit in a 5.25" drive of course.

Comment: @psusi: 3.5 inch came in 720kB and 1.44 MB formats, 5.25 inch came in 360 and 1.2MB formats. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_floppy_disk_formats

Comment: @MSalters, oh yea... been over a decade since I had to think about floppies... good riddance to bad rubbish ;)

Comment: 5.25" floppy drives often had manufacturer-specific features.  I recall using an industrial floppy drive by Panasonic that had more than 20 configuration jumpers to make it compatible with other drives or meet operational requirements.  The Kaypro was a CP/M machine that predated the IBM PC by a couple of years.  The floppy cable interface should be the same, but that does not mean that it will actually work as a replacement.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the feedback. The connectors look the same but I know there are some significant differences in the drives. For example, the 360KB rotated their disks at 300 RPM, where the 1.2MB drives rotated at a somewhat higher rotation rate. I know the 1.2MB drives can be program-controlled to write at 300 rpm, and write every other sector so it can be read by a 360KB drive as normal. There are other problems though - if you write to this same disk on a 360KB drive, the disk becomes unreadable by both 360 and 1.2 drives.

Comment: My original question was posted because I thought it depended on the motherboard's floppy drive controller to know if the machine supported both 360KB drives and 1.2MB drives. It may just take some experimenting with the actual hardware to find out if it works - I was just checking here first in case someone knew more about it.

Answer (score 0):

If the connectors look the same then they probably are the same. Some companies (notably Compaq) made deliberately incompatible interfaces but most follow the IBM PC standard. Looking at the Wikipedia page though it sounds like the Kaypro I predates IBM PCs so it could be based on Apple drives or something else entirely (it sounds like it's a 191Kb drive too).

I'm not sure but the Kaypro is probably kind of rare, it might make more sense to keep it complete as a collectors item.

EDIT: Actually the Wikipedia article is a bit confusing. [old-computers.com](http://www.old-computers.com/museum/computer.asp?c=831&st=1) has a better description and it states the Kaypro I is a late model with 360kb drives. Still might be collectable though.

Comment: The Kaypros are relatively rare. They sell for around $40 - $200 on eBay depending on the model type. The one I'm pulling the 360KB drives from is inoperable though - I'm just using it for parts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you didn't just try it and see, but yes, you can swap the drives.  You will need to go into the bios and tell it you changed the drive type.

Comment: Ok thanks - normally I would just try it but I didn't want to somehow damage the 360KB drive trying it blindly.